# 500 Internal server error when executing Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a JS script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.z').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/DeviceUsage/Edit",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            headers: {
                'RequestVerificationToken': '@TokenHeaderValue()'
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({
                deviceusage: {
                    DeviceInstanceId: $('.a').children("#DeviceInstanceId").val(),
                    UserId: $('.a').children('#UserId').val(),
                    storageId: $('.a').children('#storageId').val()

                }
            }),
            error: function (data) {
                alert("wystąpił nieokreślony błąd " + data);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.newurl);
                if (data.ok) {
                    $("#Modal").modal('hide');
                    window.location = data.newurl;
                }
                else {
                    $('.modal-body').html(data);
                }
            }
        })
    })
@functions{
    public string TokenHeaderValue()
    {
        string cookieToken, formToken;
        AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
        return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;
    }
}
});
```

And a method In DeviceUsage controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AdminAuthorization]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="StorageId,UserId,DeviceInstanceId")] DeviceUsage deviceusage)
    {
        if (deviceusage.UserId == 6 && deviceusage.StorageId==3)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Zarezerwowane urządzenie nie moze byc przypisane do biurka");
        }
        if(deviceusage.UserId==1 && deviceusage.StorageId==3)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wolne urządzenie nie może przebywać na jakimś biurku");
        }
        if((deviceusage.UserId!=1 & deviceusage.UserId!=6)&deviceusage.StorageId!=3)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Urzązenie przypisane do kogos nie moze przebywac w magazynie");
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            unitOfWork.deviceUsageRepository.Update(deviceusage);
            unitOfWork.Save();
            return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = Url.Action("Index") });
        }
        ViewBag.DeviceInstanceId = new SelectList(unitOfWork.deviceInstanceRepository.Get(), "Id", "SerialNo", deviceusage.DeviceInstanceId);
        ViewBag.StorageId = new SelectList(unitOfWork.storageRepository.Get(), "Id", "Name", deviceusage.StorageId);
        var data = unitOfWork.userRepository.Get()
        .Select(s => new
        {
            Id = s.Id,
            Credentials = s.Name + " " + s.Surname
        }
        );
        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(data, "Id", "Credentials", deviceusage.UserId);
        return PartialView(deviceusage);
    }
```

I was trying to put a breakpoint at the start of the C# method but it was never hit so Error must be somewhere else. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: url should be url: "/DeviceUsage/Create"

Comment: I pasted wrong function :X

Comment: Also you debug using chrome inspector, fiddler or firebug to see what parameters are being passed and what is the actual response when you have set custom errors as off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess any of these two attribute restricting to access the function.

```
[AdminAuthorization]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

remove it and try once.

Comment: You are correct. `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` causes problems. In order to make it working I needed to comment out this Attribute.

Answer (score 0):

500 Internal server error usually means there was a fatal error in the page you called (/DeviceUsage/Edit)

You can try manually running the page with the variables set in the page instead of posting them.

Comment: I know that. Manually testing with give me nothing because this ajax call is in modal window. So manually running it will give me nothing